# JOIN tables without repeat but need all the different values of a column

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables, resuming them:

```
    :::NEWS:::
ID  |  TITLE 
 1  |  New A  
 2  |  New B  

:::TAGTONEW:::
NEWID |  TAGID
  1   |  1 
  1   |  2
  2   |  2
  2   |  3 

:::TAGS:::
ID  |  TAG
 1  |  religion 
 2  |  sport
 3  |  politic
```

And the goal of this is to search news that match a given list of tags (e.g. News with the tags sport and religion). Ok. The problem is that when I do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM news JOIN tagtonew ON news.id = newid JOIN tags ON tagid = tags.id
WHERE tag IN ('religion','sport');
```

The result will be 3 rows, 2 of them repeating the `New A`. Ok, I can use `GROUP BY news.id` to get just one row, but the problem is that I need to return ALL the tags that match with New A (I need to return that New A is related to sport and religion), how can I do that? Requering the newid? Thanks in advance.

*edit*

The one above will result:

```
New A - religion
New A - sport
New B - sport
```

If I group will be like:

```
New A - religion
New B - sport
```

But I NEED to know that A was also related to sport, because I need to return it in a JSON. So I need the output to be something like:

```
New A - (religion, sport)
New B - sport
```

Comment: what rdbms you are using? mysql? sqlserver? oracle? what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT  a.Title
FROM    news a
        INNER JOIN tagtonew b
            ON a.id = b.newid 
        INNER JOIN tags c 
            ON b.tagid = c.id
WHERE   c.tag IN ('religion','sport')
GROUP BY a.Title
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SEE Previous SO Answer (*(rows that matches to multiple conditions)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586263/491243)

**UPDATE 1**

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  a.MovieName, '(' || GROUP_CONCAT(b.CategoryName) || ')' AS List
FROM    MovieList a
        INNER JOIN CategoryList b
            ON a.ID = b.MovieID
WHERE   b.CategoryName IN ('Comedy','Romance')
GROUP BY a.MovieName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*records may be different but may have same thought*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b60cb/1)

Comment: That's not what I need. Maybe I wasn't clear. See the edit pls.

Comment: how about this? [SQLFiddle Demo using SQLite (*click here*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b60cb/1)

Comment: Now you got it =D. Thanks very much, I did not know this command =)